# Comparing two HTML files using Grunt

Tags: html, diff, gruntjs

Is there an existing project for comparing two HTML files using Grunt, to save making a new one?

I am developing a library of Jade mixins and want to compare the output from the tests with some HTML snippets, without caring about things like whitespace/attributes being written differently.

If there is already a project out there which is close then it saves making a new one!

**EDIT:**

Started a new one and its become fairly functional:

https://github.com/metalshark/grunt-html5compare

it's now also available via npm

```
npm install grunt-html5compare
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing, no-one has authored a Grunt plugin to diff files. However, there are a few node packages that could give you a starting point:

1. https://npmjs.org/package/html-diff
2. https://npmjs.org/package/node-diff
3. https://npmjs.org/package/diff

Then to use any of these programatically you would do this:

```
var htmldiff = require('html-diff');
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // rest of your Grunt plugin
};
```

I'd be quite interested to see how this turns out, if you decide to make one. :)

Comment: Thanks Ben, thinking of using https://github.com/aredridel/html5 and the project I am making (time permitted) is hosted on https://github.com/metalshark/grunt-html5compare.

Comment: it's starting to become functional https://github.com/metalshark/grunt-html5compare

Comment: Starred it. I'll keep my eyes peeled. :-)

Comment: Think its completed now (well enough for my initial use) please feel free to kick the tyres. Added it to NPM.